# Post url in form with get method

Tags: php, url

I have a problem today!
I am trying to post a URL in form via GET method
When I post URL it automatically converts to http://example.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fanonylinq.com%2F%3Fi%3Dphpphp from http://anonylinq.com/?i=phpphp

---

Is there any way to solve this problem? I am doing this via PHP.

 because I want to echo "i" as - `<?php echo $i; ?>` Everything else is done but I am stuck at this point.
Already done this too - 
`$urlSplitted = explode('?i=', $_GET['url']); $i = $urlSplitted[1];`

Comment: use `urlencode` and `urldecode` functions

Answer (score 0):

if you want to go this road:

```
$urlSplitted = explode('?i=', $_GET['url']); $i = $urlSplitted[1];
```

you should use

```
$urlSplitted = explode('%3Fi%3D', $_GET['url']); $i = $urlSplitted[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php
That should do the trick for it.
e.g.

```
$string = $_GET['url'];
$decoded = urldecode($string);
$urlSplitted = explode('?i=', $decoded ); 
$i = $urlSplitted[1];
```

Comment: hello this is having one problem as i only need "i" in echo it also echo other variables in url, example ?i=22&o=99 i only need to echo "i" data

Comment: than first explode by ?url=, and than take the second parameter and than explode it by ?i= 
first explode will output the "url" value, and second the "i" value

Comment: Here you go : 

`$string = $_GET['url'];

$decoded = urldecode($string);

$urlSplitted = explode('?url=', $decoded ); 

$explodedByUrl  = $urlSplitted[1];

$urlExplodeToGet_i = explode('?i=', $explodedByUrl  ); 

$i = urlExplodeToGet_i [1];
echo $i;`

Comment: i made easy solution for this - just post to form via "post" method and use meta refresh, url will not be encoded when using meta refresh.

Comment: Add an answer so someone could find it if he/she needs it :)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this:
Just made form with post method to other file having meta refresh and echoed url in meta refresh value! Thats it! Meta refresh will not encode your url.